# opening serial port and reading a data string

Tags: c++

I have a weighbridge application that used to read from a Klerkscale  SASCALE before and now it also needs to read from a LS210 Opticon weighbridge.  I have added code to set the baud rates etc fot it as OPTI  but Im still getting an error of" no response from the comm port"  this error comes from the ERR00009   (if you look at the default part of the swith statement.  Can anyone help me rectify the code please.

---

```
AnsiString TfrmWeighDetails::GetMass()
{
LONG    lLastError = ERROR_SUCCESS;
bool flag;AnsiString s;
AnsiString port;
bool vTrapErrors, vIgnoreRecvEvent;

DM->vErrLineNo="GCS-21052008-70";
if ( Scale == "INVALID PORT")
{
    return "ERR0011";
}

// Attempt to open the serial port (COM1)
lLastError = serial.Open(_T(Scale.c_str()),0,0,true);

MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Privesh Test",MB_OK);

if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return "ERR0001";
}

// Setup the serial port (9600,8N1, which is the default setting)

// lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud9600,CSerial::EData8,CSerial::EParNone,CSerial::EStop1);
 lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud19200,CSerial::EData8,CSerial::EParNone,CSerial::EStop1);
if (BridgeSupplier == "OPTO")
        MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Privesh Test1",MB_OK);
        lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud19200,CSerial::EData8,CSerial::EParNone,CSerial::EStop1);
if (BridgeSupplier == "KLERKSCALE")
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud2400,CSerial::EData7,CSerial::EParOdd,CSerial::EStop1);
else
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud1200,CSerial::EData7,CSerial::EParEven,CSerial::EStop1);

if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return "ERR0002";
}

// Setup handshaking (default is no handshaking)
lLastError = serial.SetupHandshaking(CSerial::EHandshakeHardware);
MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Handshake",MB_OK);
if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return "ERR0003";
}

// Register only for the receive event
lLastError = serial.SetMask(CSerial::EEventBreak |
    CSerial::EEventCTS   |
    CSerial::EEventDSR   |
    CSerial::EEventError |
    CSerial::EEventRing  |
    CSerial::EEventRLSD  |
    CSerial::EEventRecv);
MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Receive Event",MB_OK);
if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return "ERR0004";
}

// Use 'non-blocking' reads, because we don't know how many bytes
// will be received. This is normally the most convenient mode
// (and also the default mode for reading data).
lLastError = serial.SetupReadTimeouts(CSerial::EReadTimeoutNonblocking);
MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Setup Read Timeouts",MB_OK);
if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    return "ERR0005";
}

// Create a handle for the overlapped operations
HANDLE hevtOverlapped = ::CreateEvent(0,TRUE,FALSE,0);;

if (hevtOverlapped == 0)
{
    return "ERR0006";
}

// Setup the overlapped structure
OVERLAPPED ov = {0};
ov.hEvent = hevtOverlapped;
// Open the "STOP" handle
HANDLE hevtStop = ::CreateEvent(0,TRUE,FALSE,_T("Overlapped_Stop_Event"));

if (hevtStop == 0)
    {
    return "ERR0007"  ;
}

// Keep reading data, until an EOF (CTRL-Z) has been received
bool fContinue = true;
do
{
    // Wait for an event
    lLastError = serial.WaitEvent(&ov);
    MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Serial Wait Event",MB_OK);

    if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return "ERR0010";
    }
    // Setup array of handles in which we are interested
    HANDLE ahWait[2];
    ahWait[0] = hevtOverlapped;
    ahWait[1] = hevtStop;
    // Wait until something happens
    switch (::WaitForMultipleObjects(sizeof(ahWait)/sizeof(*ahWait),ahWait,FALSE,timeout.ToInt()))
    {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            // Save event
            const CSerial::EEvent eEvent = serial.GetEventType();
            // Handle break event
            if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventBreak)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL," BREAK received ","Comm Program",MB_OK);
            }
            // Handle CTS event
            if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventCTS)
            {
                flag =   serial.GetCTS();
                if (flag)
                    s = "ON";
                else
                    s = "OFF";
                MessageBox(NULL,(AnsiString("Clear to send ") + s).c_str(),"Comm Prog",MB_OK);
            }
            // Handle DSR event
            if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventDSR)
            {
                flag  = serial.GetDSR();
                if (flag)
                    s = "ON";
                else
                    s = "OFF";
                MessageBox(NULL,(AnsiString("Data set ready ") + s).c_str(),"Comm Prog",MB_OK);
            }
            // Handle error event
            vTrapErrors=false;
            if ((eEvent & CSerial::EEventError)&&
                 (vTrapErrors))  // Although errors encountered, mass still read on XP OS. Therefore, errors suppressed on XP i.e.vTrapErrors=false - MZI12112007
            {
                //MessageBox(NULL,"### ERROR: ");
                switch (serial.GetError())
                {
                    case CSerial::EErrorBreak:        MessageBox(NULL,"Break condition","Com Prog",MB_OK);            break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorFrame:        MessageBox(NULL,"Framing error","Com Prog",MB_OK);            break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorIOE:        MessageBox(NULL,"IO device error","Com Prog",MB_OK);            break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorMode:        MessageBox(NULL,"Unsupported mode","Com Prog",MB_OK);            break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorOverrun:    MessageBox(NULL,"Buffer overrun","Com Prog",MB_OK);            break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorRxOver:        MessageBox(NULL,"Input buffer overflow","Com Prog",MB_OK);    break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorParity:        MessageBox(NULL,"Input parity error","Com Prog",MB_OK);        break;
                    case CSerial::EErrorTxFull:        MessageBox(NULL,"Output buffer full","Com Prog",MB_OK);        break;
//                    default:                  MessageBox(NULL,"Unknown","Com Prog",MB_OK); break; // Error 0 is UNKNOWN but is a Success error therefore no need to handle -- MZI12112007
                }
                //printf(" ###\n");
            }

            // Handle ring event
            if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventRing)
            {
                Sleep(2000);
            }
            // Handle RLSD/CD event
            if (eEvent & CSerial::EEventRLSD)
            {
                flag  = serial.GetRLSD();
                if (flag)
                    s = "ON";
                else
                    s = "OFF";
                MessageBox(NULL,(AnsiString("RLSD/CD ") + s).c_str(),"Comm Prog",MB_OK);
            }
            Timer1->Enabled = false; //switch off the timeout
            // Handle data receive event
            Sleep (1000);    // when no pause, no mass read on XP. Therefore, this ensures system gets in sync with Comm Device - MZI12112007
            vIgnoreRecvEvent=true; // On XP, the Receive event does not seem to be triggered. Therefore this code was included to forcce WBR to work on Xp -- MZI12112007
            if ((eEvent & CSerial::EEventRecv)||vIgnoreRecvEvent)
            {
                // Read data, until the reading from scale is stable
                DWORD dwBytesRead = 0;
                do
                {
                    char szBuffer[101];
                    // Read data from the COM-port
                    lLastError = serial.Read(szBuffer,sizeof(szBuffer)-1,&dwBytesRead);
                    if (lLastError != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    {
                        ShowError(serial.GetLastError(), _T("Unable to read from COM-port."));
                        return "ERR0008";
                    }
                    if (dwBytesRead > 0)
                    {
                        // Finalize the data, so it is a valid string
                        szBuffer[dwBytesRead] = '\0';
                        AnsiString result = GetStableReading(szBuffer,BridgeSupplier);
                        // Display the data
                        if ( result == "OVERCAPACITY" || result == "BELOWCAPACITY")
                        {
                            serial.Close();
                            return result;
                        }
                        else if ( result != "ERROR" && result != "")
                        {
                            serial.Close();
                            return result;
                        }
                    }
                }
                while ((dwBytesRead > 0 )&&(result == ""));
            }
        }
        break;
    case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
    {
        // Set the continue bit to false, so we'll exit
        fContinue = false;
    }
    break;
    default:
    {
        //No response from comm port
        serial.Close();
        return "ERR0009";
    }
}
}
while (fContinue);
// Close the port again
serial.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is `timeout` set to?

Comment: By the way, you don't know if the `WaitForMultipleObjects` function timeouts or fails. You might want to handle those two differently (for example report the error on failure).

Comment: the problem is that i never write this code, I do not even know c++ alot.  I just got roped into this as the guy who wrote this left a long time ago so I do not know what effect it will have by changing the code or how to modify it.  so im in a big dilemna here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please add more curly braces to the code to separate different choices, like this:

```
if (BridgeSupplier == "OPTO") {
    MessageBox(NULL,AnsiString(lLastError).c_str(),"Privesh Test1",MB_OK);
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud19200,CSerial::EData8,CSerial::EParNone,CSerial::EStop1);
} else if (BridgeSupplier == "KLERKSCALE") {
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud2400,CSerial::EData7,CSerial::EParOdd,CSerial::EStop1);
} else {
    lLastError = serial.Setup(CSerial::EBaud1200,CSerial::EData7,CSerial::EParEven,CSerial::EStop1);
}
```

because currently your code setups the port for OPTO and then sets the port again for the default "else" condition, overwriting the setup for OPTO.

Comment: Holy smoke, i cant believe I missed that. I feel so kak now

Comment: Hey, no worries, happens to everybody. That is why I enclose even one-line conditional statements in {}, this way it is easier to extend the code later. In any case, does the code work now? If not, what is happening?

Comment: That part of the code working now. Im doing some inline debugging (break point and step over) line by lie to have a look at the string received so i can write code for each of the three scales, ie determining the starting point ad then the substring to read etc. boy what a mission.  Anyway thanks Victor for spotting my booooo :)

Comment: thanks Victor.  BTW I sorted the string part out and all is working.  I understand the whole process now.  Thanks for your assistance

Comment: hi Victor, do you by any chance have the oracle connection to open and read a socket connection.  Ttrying to transfer this to an oracle database

Comment: Hi Privesh, sorry I have no Oracle experience.